# Identify the latest series of Continuous same value in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame (Date in dd-mm-yyyy format):

```
import pandas as pd
data={'Id':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
  'Date':['20-10-2022', '20-10-2022', '20-10-2022', '21-10-2022', '21-10-2022', '21-10-2022',
          '22-10-2022', '22-10-2022', '23-10-2022', '23-10-2022', '24-10-2022', '24-10-2022',
          '25-10-2022', '25-10-2022', '26-10-2022', '26-10-2022', '26-10-2022', '27-10-2022',
          '27-10-2022', '27-10-2022']}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df


   Id        Date
0   A  20-10-2022
1   B  20-10-2022
2   C  20-10-2022
3   A  21-10-2022
4   B  21-10-2022
5   C  21-10-2022
6   B  22-10-2022
7   C  22-10-2022
8   A  23-10-2022
9   C  23-10-2022
10  B  24-10-2022
11  C  24-10-2022
12  B  25-10-2022
13  C  25-10-2022
14  A  26-10-2022
15  B  26-10-2022
16  C  26-10-2022
17  A  27-10-2022
18  B  27-10-2022
19  C  27-10-2022
```

This is the Final DataFrame that I want:

[image: Final DataFrame that I want]

I have tried the following code:

```
# Find first occurance and last occurance of any given Id.
df_first_duplicate = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep='first')
df_first_duplicate.rename(columns = {'Date':'DateOfFirstOccurance'}, inplace = True)
df_first_duplicate.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
df_last_duplicate = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep='last')
df_last_duplicate.rename(columns = {'Date':'DateOfLastOccurance'}, inplace = True)
df_last_duplicate.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
# Merge the above two df's on key
df_merged = pd.merge(df_first_duplicate, df_last_duplicate, on='Id')
df_merged
```

But this is the output that I get:

```
  Id DateOfFirstOccurance DateOfLastOccurance
0  A           20-10-2022          27-10-2022
1  B           20-10-2022          27-10-2022
2  C           20-10-2022          27-10-2022
```

What should I do to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

records = []
for key, group in df.groupby(by='Id'):
    filt = group['Date'].diff(-1).dt.days >= -1 
    filt.iloc[filt.shape[0]-1] = True
    max_false_index = filt[~filt].index.max()
    min_date = group['Date'].min() if type(max_false_index) == float else group.loc[max_false_index+1:, 'Date'].min()
    records.append([key, min_date, group['Date'].max()])
    
pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Id', 'DateOfFirstOccurance', 'DateOfLastOccurance'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

Sort your data by `Id` and `Date`. Use [`pandas.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) to get the difference of each row compared to the last one, change it with `dt.days` to a floating number and create a boolean Series by comparing each value if it is greater/equal to 1. Convert the boolean Series from True/False to 1/0 with `astype(int)` and build the cumulative sum. The idx with the biggest value is the first/last occurence of your data.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'Date'])

out = (
    df
    .groupby('Id')['Date']
    .agg(
        first_occurence = lambda x: x[
            (x.diff().dt.days>1)
            .astype(int)
            .cumsum()
            .idxmax()
        ],
        last_occurence = lambda x: x[
            (x.diff().dt.days==1)
            .astype(int)
            .cumsum()
            .idxmax()
        ],
    )
)

print(out)
```

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation to approach the problem.